# How to fetch data from multiple MongoDB Collections using Clojure Map

Tags: mongodb, clojure, congomongo

I am using clojure to fetch data from multiple MongoDB collections.

```
(ns mongofetch
  (:require [somnium.congomongo :as m]))

(m/with-mongo (m/make-connection "testdb") (mapv m/fetch coll))
```

Here, coll is the vector where collection-names are stored. This is working fine as it fetches data from multiple MongoDB collections and returns a vector comprising of sequences (returns sequences for each collection) with documents. But, I'm getting an error while using `map` instead of `mapv` (for following code-snippet).

```
(m/with-mongo (m/make-connection "testdb") (map m/fetch coll))
```

The error is - `java.lang.AssertionError: Assert failed: (connection? conn)`

Why is it throwing an AssertionError and how it can be resolved using `map` only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` is lazy and should not in general be used for side-effecting functions. Your connection has closed before `map` has finished processing. If you really want to use it you should wrap it in a `doall`.

```
(doall (map side-effect! coll))
```

Comment: `doall` forces the lazy-seq to be realized. Here, does the use of `doall` cause the seq to reside in memory at one time?

Comment: @sammy, yes it does. If you don't care about the results you could use `dorun`. Because you are fetching I imagine you do.